# Get total number of matches along with result in algolia

Tags: algolia

I am looking for something like FOUND_ROWS() in mysql select query in algolia results as I need to keep a track of how many total results to expect. Is there someway to get this in Algolia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to obtain the number of results is to access the `nbHits` value which is available in the JSON response of every search call.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted.